# dynamically create widget for every attached device

Tags: qt, dynamic, qt-creator, device

I would like to ask you for a help with Qt 5.1.1.

I have an application which handles with serial connected device. Devices are on RS 485 so under one USB connection I can communicate with more devices at once.

Now my problem. Every device has own communication code in protocol.

For example, every device send me code '$D01' or '$D05' in case this is a device 1 or 5. So I can know how many are there. Or maybe I can do it hard in software so that I will say the application which device numbers are there.

But what I need is to have for every device there own subwindow for communication. The windows are the same. I would like to know how to do it dynamically so that after giving the addresses of devices I can operate with every in its own frame, subwindow or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy in Qt.
First you create your custom widget (the "subwindow" in your question) with File->New->Qt->Qt Designer From Class. Then lay it out using the designer pane of QtCreator. So you have a new custom class, e.g. MyWidget that is derived from QWidget with your custom layout etc.

Then you have your main window, e.g. MyMainWindow. You create a container widget within that main window where you want your widgets to reside in and give it a layout, e.g. you say "lay out vertically". Other than that you keep the container widget empty (just a plain QWidget with a layout attached).

Now in your code, whenever you enumber a new USB device, you do it as follows:

- create your custom widget, e.g. `MyWidget *widget = new MyWidget(this);`
- add the widget, e.g. `container->layout()->addWidget(widget)` or containerLayout->addWidget(), depending on whether you named your layout explicitely or not
- use a custom constructor in your MyWidget class or setters etc. to fill it with the appropriate information

As you can see you can still use the standard UI layouting approach of Qt and with a little extra code have a dynamic amount of widgets.

When your window gets too busy, you can change the container to something else: MdiArea, StackedWidget, TabbedWidget, etc.